missing entitlements when uploading via fastlane
I am using fastlane and match to upload an app to test flight. The app requires com.apple.developer.storekit.external-link.account to be activated.
My identifier has activated the capabilities and when I look at provisional profile, it also has it, but when the app has been uploaded, it's missing (although all other entitlements are there).
Now it gets weird:
Every time I run my flow I delete derived data, deletes all downloaded provisional profiles and use match to redownload them with read only (force is not an option).
It does not work. I go to Apple dev and Toggles the capability off and on and saves. This invalidates the profile. I press edit and save. So no real changes. Run my flow and the app is uploaded correctly WITH the correct capabilities. Runs the flow again without the manual steps and the entitlements will be missing once again.
Repeats the toggle stuff and the subsequent behavior repeats itself. Same flow and same code and same settings, app and profile....
I am building automated flows so this does not really work for me....
Heeeelp...
I replicated the behaviour several times

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

but my code uploads the apps successfully in respect with 99.9% of the content and the entitlements are included if toggling... I am not sure which code to include
